# Polymorphism doesn't work in C++ lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a method like this:

```
void syncOperation(ProgressCallback& progressCallback);
```

where `ProgressCallback` is:

```
class ProgressCallback
{
public:
    virtual void onProgress(std::size_t currValue, std::size_t maxValue) {}
    virtual void onDone() {}
};
```

and I want to make it async, so I do the following:

```
void asyncOperation(ProgressCallback& progressCallback)
{
    auto impl = [this](ProgressCallback& progressCallback_)
    {
        syncOperation(progressCallback_);
    };
    jobsPool.addJob(std::bind(impl, progressCallback));
}
```

but behaviour of `progressCallback` in the 2nd case (`asyncOperation(ProgressCallback&)`) isn't polymorphic, it calls methods of the base class always and that is definitely not what I expect. So my questions are: 1)why is it happening and 2)how to fix it (yes, I know I can just stop using lambdas in my case, but maybe there is some traditional workaround)?

Comment: Why are you juggling lambdas and `std::bind` instead of simply `[&]{ syncOperation(progressCallback); }`?

Comment: @drolmal that question is wildly unrelated

Comment: Nir that post  explains in detail a) why there aren't poly lambdas and b) how to fix it...

Comment: Because Job has the following definition: typedef `std::function<void ()> Job`.

Comment: @drolmal That post is talking about the lambda itself being polymorphic, and statically polymorphic, i.e. generics, i.e. a lambda which has a templated operator(). This is talking about why inheritance polymorphism is not working in a normal lambda. There's literally zero connection.

Comment: In general, I'd consider using smart pointers instead of references for lifetime-safety.

Answer (score 2):

The code you show has no room for polymorphism, but lets assume that `asyncOperation` is passed a reference to something derived from `ProgressCallback`:

You're creating a copy when you pass your reference to `bind`.  The object that bind returns stores the value based on the type information it has about it.  It only knows that it has a reference to `ProgressCallback` so that's what kind of value it stores.  This causes a slicing copy.

You need to wrap your value in a reference_wrapper:

```
jobsPool.addJob(bind(impl, ref(progressCallback));
```

Or you could use lambda (better):

```
jobsPool.addJob([impl,&progressCallback](){ impl(progressCallback); });
```

**Or you could just create the `impl` so that it does everything on its own.**

What you're doing now is relatively equivalent to:

```
jobsPool.addJob([impl,=progressCallback]() mutable { impl(progressCallback); });
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I meant.

Comment: You should highlight the lifetime danger here.  Personally, I'd either have a pointer to make the lifetime issues more explicit, and possibly use a shared ownership smart pointer of some kind.

Comment: I don't see how this code makes sense, you are calling `impl` from inside a lambda that doesn't capture it.

Comment: @Yakk it's still completely needless to create a first lambda called impl, and then capture it in a second lambda. Just create one lambda and be done with it.

Comment: @NirFriedman I just fixed the typo.  Eddie can pick how to fix the design issue implied.  I didn't want to touch the text, I just wanted to patch the code so it is defined behavior and compiles and does what Eddie obviously intended it should do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define a lambda, and then use bind, or use two lambdas, you can do this all in one go:

```
void asyncOperation(ProgressCallback& progressCallback)
{
    jobsPool.addJob([&] { syncOperation(progressCallback); });
}
```

As noted, in the original code you're being bitten because of the slicing copy that is occurring. Because of how template argument deduction works, deferred function calls like `std::bind` need to have by reference arguments passed via reference wrappers. This rather odd behavior is another good reason not to use `bind` at all once you have access to lambdas. Though note that this behavior also applies to `std::thread`.

Be aware that storing a lambda that captures something by reference is quite a dangerous thing to do. You could call `asyncOperation` with a progressCallback object which is then alive, and it is possible that the object is destructed by the time that lambda is executed, causing undefined behavior.